# Shape Key Animations Not Included in FBX Export Despite Baking in Blender 4.0.1

Tags: export, .fbx, nla-editor

[image]I'm experiencing an issue with exporting an animated object with shape keys to FBX in Blender 4.0.1. The shape keys themselves are present when I re-import the FBX file into Blender, but the associated animations do not play.

What I've done so far:

Animated the shape keys in Blender and confirmed they're working within the application.
Baked the animation using the 'Bake Action' feature with 'Visual Keying' and 'Bake Data' to 'Object'.
Verified that the baked action is the active action for the object.
Exported the object to FBX with 'Baked Animation', 'NLA Strips', and 'All Actions' enabled.
Re-imported the FBX file into Blender, where I found the shape keys intact, but the animation is static and won't play.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Ensured 'Automatic Bone Orientation' is unchecked during import.
Checked both the Dope Sheet and NLA Editor for the presence and correct assignment of the action.
Confirmed that I am in 'Object Mode' and the playhead is at the start of the timeline.
Despite these steps, the animation does not play after re-importing the FBX file. I am seeking insights into why the animation data might not be exporting or why it's not being read correctly upon re-import.

Questions:

Are there additional export settings that need to be enabled for the animation to be included in the FBX file?
Could there be compatibility issues with the FBX version and Blender 4.0.1?
Is there a known bug or limitation with shape key animations in FBX files in Blender 4.0.1?
I would appreciate any guidance or assistance on this matter. Attached are screenshots from the Blender interface, showing the shape key panel, baked keyframes, and export settings.